# read_csv: Expecting 3 Tasks per Partition, But Only Getting One

Tags: dataframe, task, dask

The link shows the result from running 3 lines of code in Jupyter Notebook:
[read parking entries into a dataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmQXW.png)

In Jesse Daniel's "Data Science with Python and Dask" book, it clearly states that I should expect to see 99 tasks, not 33:

> The graph consists of 99 nodes because each partition requires three
> operations to be created: reading the raw data, splitting the data
> into the appropriately sized block, and initializing the underlying
> DataFrame object. In total, 33 partitions with 3 tasks per partition
> results in 99 tasks.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and *DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question*.

Answer (score 0):

Dask performs "optimization" on the graph before execution. In the case that you have linear chains of tasks (each task depends on only one precursor, and the precursor only has one dependant), dask may *fuse* tasks together.

Documentation: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/optimize.html

Note that the book you reference is 18 months old (since publication) and Dask is a rapidly-evolving project.

Comment: I did not import or call any optimization functions. Are you saying that the newer version of Dask is "auto-fusing" linear chains of tasks?

Comment: You do not need to call optimise, dask does these things automatically (especially if sending the work to a distributed scheduler); but the read_csv machinery I think has been rewritten a lot since your reference. You can view the raw dask graph as `dict(df.dask)`.